# Running unit test in the build agent using Visual Studio Services

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to run unit tests in the build server of Visual Studio. Unfortunately, I get this message:

> No test found. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors,
>   platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

I gave it a test setting files to run, specified the run settings, set the MSBUILD to x86 and the target platform to x86:

Emulator WVGA

Tried to specify the regex pattern to find the test DLLs. Still no luck. Am I doing something wrong ?

I'm using MSTest.

**Edit**: Apparently, I believe I mistakenly thought that Windows Phone Unit Test project is different from a Normal Unit Test Project. It was able to see the test sources when I just use normal unit test project. Correct me if I'm wrong. Question now is what's the point of the Windows Phone Unit Test App?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a third party test framework you will need to install it on the controller server.

Check this http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/create-and-run-unit-tests-vs#frameworks

Comment: I don't have third party test framework. It's the actual `Windows Phone Unit Test` project vs `Standard Unit Test` project